# A title in a Chrome App title bar

Tags: google-chrome-app

Sorry for the naive question but...

I'd like to add a *title* and an icon in what is (purposely, I guess) called a *title bar* in a Chrome (packaged) App.

Is it really/still impossible? All the answers I read are using frameless windows, which I don't want. For, what I want is a window with the OS native layout.

I've tested a `background.html` page with a `<title>` set, but it will never display either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, doesn't seem to be possible anyhow with the standard window decoration as opposed to frameless.

Comment: OK so it's rather a *no-title* bar :-/